# Exchange server uses wrong accepted domain when sending to specific external addresses

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a Exchange 2010 with two different accepted domains (let's call them domain1.com and domain2.com). Some of the users have email addresses with both domains and some have ony one of the domains. A couple of the users having only one of the domains (example2.com), but some of the receipients get the address @example1.com in the header.

Sometimes when user1@domain2.com sends emails the recipient gets it from postmaster@domain1.com.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the message tracking logs?

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. Can you try to rephrase your question?